# cannot weight paint on certain parts of the model

Tags: weight-painting

I am trying to weight paint a character model. I flooded the whole head red. [image: head]

However, there are still green areas behind the teeth I did not get to. [image: teeth]
For some reason, I could not weight paint these areas. Nothing happens when I drag my mouse across them. They are causing artifacts at the moment when I try to move the head around. [image: artifacts]

Comment: In Brush Settings > Advanced, disable Front Faces Only, under Falloff > Falloff Shape, enable Projected, and make sure that Front-Face Falloff is disabled

Comment: Also in Edit mode, with transparency, you could select all these vertices and assign them to the vertex group you want

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem when you can't weight paint on certain areas of the mesh:

Go to **weight Paint Mode**, and press on **Vertex Selection** icon:
[image]

Go into **Wireframe** display to select through your mesh.
**Select all of the vertices** of the part you want to be painted.

Go to '**Weights**' > '**Set Weight**'

[image]

The entire selection has been assigned the weight.

Edit: Make sure also that "restrict" is not enabled in Tool options.

Comment: This is an alternative method but for complex meshes this will not work nicely, the "painting" part gets lost. But thank you for taking the time and writing such a good awnser