# Weight paint only working on certain parts of a model

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

I followed [this](https://youtu.be/4z7G4TyKE9g?t=536) tutorial to rig a character and animate it, however, when I got to the weight paint part, the weight paint only worked on certain parts of the model I created.

See below:
[image: Weight paint effecting arms and legs, but not the body]

The weight paint is only affecting the arms and legs. All the models are joined together.

I already tried solutions like when someone posted a similar problem [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159058/weight-paint-works-on-only-one-area) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234662/cannot-weight-paint-on-certain-parts-of-the-model) to no avail, so please do not mark this as a repeated question.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The weights are assigned to vertices by vertex groups. It looks like the blue body/head is a cube with only 8 vertices. If so, click at the corners to assign the weights. If you need finer detail, you will need to subdivide the mesh to create more vertices.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem!